# Why doesn't the example given by the wexpect library work on win64 OS？

Tags: python-3.x

I wanted to use python to interact with Windows command prompts, and looking up the data found that wexpect can help me do that.But when I ran the example given to me by the official wexpect library, some errors occurred.

```py
    import wexpect
    child = wexpect.spawn('cmd.exe')
    child.expect('>')
    child.sendline('dir')# 
    child.expect('>')
    print(child.before)
    child.sendline('exit')
```

The following error occurred when running child.sendline(),how to solve it?

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/0work/untitled/demo/wexpectDemo.py", line 5, in <module>
    child.sendline('dir')
  File "D:\0work\python3.7.3\lib\site-packages\wexpect.py", line 813, in sendline
    n = self.send(s)
  File "D:\0work\python3.7.3\lib\site-packages\wexpect.py", line 844, in send
    c = self.wtty.write(s)
  File "D:\0work\python3.7.3\lib\site-packages\wexpect.py", line 1404, in write
    wrote = self.__consin.WriteConsoleInput(records)
pywintypes.error: (6, 'WriteConsoleInput', '句柄无效。')
```

Comment: "句柄无效。" means "The handle is invalid.", according to Google Translate

Comment: Which version do you use? Please use [v3.2.0](https://pypi.org/project/wexpect/3.2.0/) `pip install wexpect==3.2.0` or higher, and try the *new structure* by setting `WEXPECT_SPAWN_CLASS` environment variable to `SpawnPipe`, and try again. If the problem still occurs please open a new [issue](https://github.com/raczben/wexpect/issues).

Answer (score 0):

Could it be anything to do with venv? (see this issue) https://github.com/raczben/wexpect/issues/42

I just fixed the same issue by removing venv.